Publishing custom tag for repo cloned by BitBucket plugin?
I cloned a BitBucket repo in Jenkins via the BitBucket plugin.  At the end of the build, I would like to push a custom tag to the remote repo.  However, Git Publisher requires it to be set up with the Git Plugin.  Doesn't this defeat the purpose of cloning with BitBucket Plugin if I still need to set up an SSH key to push the tag with Git?  Or am I missing a solution that uses the BitBucket Plugin?  I have also tried replacing my $CustomVersion with /refs/tags/$CustomVersion.


This is starting to make me think that Git Publisher doesn't play nice with BitBucket.
